# Routing issue with AngularJS project using yeoman setup

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, angular-routing, yeoman-generator-angular, angularjs-1.6

I have setup a new Angular project using yeoman. Angular version is 1.6.0. Project setup was successful but I have been facing an issue with routing

Task runner - Grunt

When I run the project in local my local page will load with URL

http://localhost:9000/#!/

I was expecting http://localhost:9000/#/

When clicked on About link browser is routed to

http://localhost:9000/#!/%23%2Fabout

Expectation: http://localhost:9000/#/about

When I click home link browser is routed to

http://localhost:9000/#!/%23%2F

Expectation: http://localhost:9000/#/

What might be the issue? I have no such issues in my other system where I'm using AngularJS 1.5.8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got resolved with following code.You can write in your app.js file

```
 $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```

Comment: You can go through this link  https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/1380