# Getting "#!/(state)" in url AngularJS states

Tags: angularjs

I'm doing an application using OAuth so first of, a php-page is loaded to authenticate with OAuth. When finished the callback php script redirects to the start page of my angular application.

```
//  Redirect user to the startpage of the application
header("location: http://localhost/app/start.html");
```

Here, Angular is instantiated, all scripts are loaded and the stateprovider is supposed to redirect to the .otherwise state here.

```
app
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('main/front');

$stateProvider
.state('main',{
    url: '/main',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl:'templates/menu.html'
})

    .state('main.frontpage',{
        url: '/front',
        templateUrl:'templates/frontPage.html'
    })
});
```

The redirect works fine and i'm getting to the correct page main/front though i'm getting a weird url that JQuery keeps alarming about.

> http://localhost/app/start.html#!/main/front

JQuery error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #!/main/front

Why is the url getting the #! sign in there?

EDIT: The JQuery error appears to be thrown else where. not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got resolved with following code.

```
 $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```

or else go 
[Routing issue with AngularJS project using yeoman setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140716/routing-issue-with-angularjs-project-using-yeoman-setup/41142588#41142588)

Comment: I went through that rabbit hole and got to the page https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/1380 where they recommended downgrading to angular 1.5.8.

This appears to remove the "!", still leaving the "#". JQuery is still throwing error at this 
>"Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/front"

Comment: No need to downgrade @TimothyKarvonen and you can check after that.my version not changed after adding that

Comment: correct, with your solution @Shiva it removes the "!" at angular 1.6.0. Then why is JQuery complaining about the url?

Comment: Oh.. This appears to ba a problem outside angular, the error is thrown in a different part of my application. debugging java script amirite. Thanks @Shiva for your help