# angular ui router dynamic url

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I got urls with dynamic  data (using `jquery.datatables`)
When I write the href like "#!/app/kid/edit/13333"
The page remove the base page url

For exmample if the full page url is "http://www.aaa.com/kid.html#!/app/kid/edit/13333"
and I write `<a href="#!/app/kid/edit/2222">link</a>`
This remove the page url kid.html and add the hash to  the root.

This is my code

```
   {
          targets: [1],
          title: $scope.columns[1].name,
          mRender: function (data, type, row) {
              return "<a class='link1' href='#!/app/kid/edit/" + row[0] + "' />" + data + "</a>";
          },
          visible: $scope.selectedColumns[1].selected,
          orderable: $scope.columns[1].sorted,

      },
```

BTW in angular 1.6.1 the url has "#!" instead of just "#", what does the reason for this.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41427609/getting-state-in-url-angularjs-states/41427733#41427733  go through this link

Comment: the  $locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); remove the "!" from the url but does not resolve that the links navigate to the root instead of current page.