# AngularJS Routing not working on 1.6.4 even with #! on Google Apps

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm running the following code on Google Apps and noticed that Route is not functioning while other AngularJS functions work. Clicking on editprofile link doesn't do anything. Tried a lot, but in vain...

**HTML-HEAD**

```
<head>
  <base target="_blank">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  <title>Activity Details</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css">

  <style>
    .disclaimer {
      width: 480px;
      color: #646464;
      margin: 20px auto;
      padding: 0 16px;
      text-align: center;
      font: 400 12px Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    }

    .disclaimer a {
      color: #009688;
    }

    #credit{
      display: none;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-materialize/0.2.2/angular-materialize.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

**HTML-BODY**

```
<li>
  <a href="#!/editprofile"><i class="large material-icons">account_circle</i></a>
</li>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.materialize','ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/editprofile', {
    templateUrl: 'editprofile.html'
  }).otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/editprofile'
  });   
}]);
```

**editprofile.html**

```
<div>
  <h1>London</h1>
  <h3>London is the capital city of England.</h3>
  <p>It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan 
    area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide demo on plunker or jsfiddle?

Comment: you can try with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140716/routing-issue-with-angularjs-project-using-yeoman-setup/41142588#41142588

Comment: did you set up correctly an element where renders the view inside your HTML? like `<div ui-view></div>`

Comment: I've set this view:       <div ng-view></div>. When I copy my code in plnkr in this project: http://plnkr.co/edit/sN9TagVBOdX3mkrxaTiu?p=preview it works. I'm not sure if Google Apps is the culprit here.

Comment: Ajay, that option doesn't work as well. I've tried it after removing the exclamation character.